# postData for subgrid in jqgrid not working?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

Hi I have a jqgrid with a subgrid which calls into a servlet.
I am sending some data to the servlet using POST but the same data doesn't get sent when the call for the subgrid is made. This is my JS:

```
$("#testsTable").jqGrid({
  mtype: "POST",
  url: "GetCurrentStatusServlet",
  postData: {buildPath :"C:\\Test\\01"},
  datatype: "xml",
     colNames:['TestCase Name', 'Last Update', 'Status'],
     colModel:[
      {name:'name',index:'name', width:90},
      {name:'lastupdate',index:'lastupdate', width:100},
      {name:'status',index:'status', width:80, align:"right"}   
     ],
     rowNum:10,
     autowidth: true,
     rowList:[10,20,30],
     pager: $('#pager1'),
     sortname: 'id',
     viewrecords: true,
     multiselect: true,
  caption: "Tests",
     sortorder: "desc",
     subGrid: true,
     subGridUrl : "GetCurrentStatusServlet",
     subGridModel: [ {
       name:  ['TestCase Name', 'Last Update', 'Status'],
       width : [100, 200, 80],
       params: ['name']}]
 }).navGrid('#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

So how can I postData also to the subgrid servlet? is there any way to specify subgridPostData?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the suggestion with `subgridPostData` good. Probably you should post the corresponding feature request in the [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/).

Now you can implement the same feature itself using [serializeSubGridData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#events) event. Just define a new jqGrid parameter with the name which you like, for example `subgridPostData` and use it inside of your [serializeSubGridData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#events) event handler:

```
$("#testsTable").jqGrid({
    ...
    subGrid: true,
    subGridUrl: "GetCurrentStatusServlet",
    subgridPostData: {foo: "bar"},
    serializeSubGridData: function(postdata) {
        return $.extend(postdata, this.p.subgridPostData);
    },
    ...
});
```