# jqgrid nested subgrid 4th level subgrid always returns first rowid of the subgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, nested, subgrid

jqGrid v4.3.2
ie9
win7enterprise

I'm using the following code to generate subgrids:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html - > Advanced -> Grid as SubGrid

I do this and i have

1st level subgrid *OK*
  2nd level subgrid *OK*
    3rd level subgrid *OK*
      4th level subgrid *It loads the subgrid OK for every row of the 3rd Lvl sg, but it shows data only of the first row id of the 3rd Lvl sg*

When I check the developer tools I see that the request always sends the id of the first row of the third subgrid, I know how to append custom parameters with postData which I have already tried and also this answer from Oleg K [postData for subgrid in jqgrid not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449130/postdata-for-subgrid-in-jqgrid-not-working) (this one doesn't work in my case, data is not added to the request)

I've tried to return the rowdid from the following events but no luck, it stills returns the first row id of the third subgrid and thus, for every row on the third subgrid the children subgrid always returns the same.

```
subGridRowExpanded  //always returns first row id of the third grid
onSelectRow  //doesn't fire if we click the + icon for expanding the subgrid
beforeSelectRow  //doesn't fire at all
```

Another strange behaviour is that if i click any row on the third level subgrid it only selects the first row.

No, using treegrid is not an option, sorry.

I'm thinking of binding a click event on the plus icon (first cell) of each row of the 3rd level subgrid and fire a expandSubGridRow, but the question remains, how do I get the rowid of the row I clicked *of the third level subgrid*?

Best regards and thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

```
jQuery("#listsg11").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=1',
    datatype: "xml",
    height: 190,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    rowNum:8,
    rowList:[8,10,20,30],
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    multiselect: false,
    subGrid: true,
    caption: "Grid as Subgrid",
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table>");
        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url:"subgrid.php?q=2&id="+row_id,
            datatype: "xml",
            colNames: ['No','Item','Qty','Unit','Line Total'],
            colModel: [
                {name:"num",index:"num",width:80,key:true},
                {name:"item",index:"item",width:130},
                {name:"qty",index:"qty",width:70,align:"right"},
                {name:"unit",index:"unit",width:70,align:"right"},
                {name:"total",index:"total",width:70,align:"right",sortable:false}
            ],
            subGrid: true,
            caption: "Grid as Subgrid",
            subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id2, row_id2) {
                var subgrid_table_id2;
                subgrid_table_id2 = subgrid_id2+"_t";
                $("#"+subgrid_id2).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id2+"' class='scroll'></table>");
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id2).jqGrid({
                    url:"subgrid.php?q=3&id="+row_id2,
                    datatype: "xml",
                    colNames: ['No','Item','Qty','Unit','Line Total'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name:"num",index:"num",width:80,key:true},
                        {name:"item",index:"item",width:130},
                        {name:"qty",index:"qty",width:70,align:"right"},
                        {name:"unit",index:"unit",width:70,align:"right"},
                        {name:"total",index:"total",width:70,align:"right",sortable:false}
                ],
                subGrid: true,
                caption: "Grid as Subgrid",
                subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id3, row_id3) {
                    var subgrid_table_id3;
                    subgrid_table_id3 = subgrid_id3+"_t";
                    $("#"+subgrid_id3).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id3+"' class='scroll'></table></div>");
                    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id3).jqGrid({
                        url:"subgrid.php?q=4&id="+row_id3,
                        datatype: "xml",
                        colNames: ['No','Item','Qty','Unit','Line Total'],
                        colModel: [
                            {name:"num",index:"num",width:80,key:true},
                            {name:"item",index:"item",width:130},
                            {name:"qty",index:"qty",width:70,align:"right"},
                            {name:"unit",index:"unit",width:70,align:"right"},
                            {name:"total",index:"total",width:70,align:"right",sortable:false}
                    ]
                    });
                }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I suppose you used wrong rowids (duplicates if ids) during *filling* of the main grid. The demo " - > Advanced -> Grid as SubGrid" don't have subrids on the 2nd level. So I can't reproduce the problem which you describe and can open only subgrids on the top-level. You should include test data and the JavaScript code which define jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg I jave included an example per your request.

Comment: @Oleg, I have followed your advices and found that I indeed had duplicates id's, that was the cause of failure.

Can you please post your comment as answer so I can mark your answer as the accepted one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still suppose that you have some id conflicts between *data in *all** subgrids displayed on the page. For example if you inserts on some level in some from opened grids the data having "1" as the rowid no other data in any subgrid should be inserted with the same subgrid.

For understanding: You use `key:true` for the `"num"` column on all level of subgrids. The corresponding value will be not just used in `"num"` column inside of grid cell (inside of `<td>here</td>`). It will be also used as the value of `id` attributes of the row of the grid or subgrid (`<tr>`). HTML don't permit id duplicates on the page. So it you do insert elements with id duplicates you can have some strange effects which could be different in different web browsers. For example you will try to select one row and it will be selected another one. You can also have much more hard problems as selection of rows. So you should fill the grids so than **ids will be unique on the whole page**.

To be sure that the problem with id duplicates is not exists you can use `idPrefix` option. On the level 0 you can use

```
idPrefix: "m"
```

(from main) for example. For the subgrid on the next level you can use

```
idPrefix: "s" + row_id + "_"
```

for the next level subgrid

```
idPrefix: "s" + row_id + "_" + row_id2 + "_"
```

and

```
idPrefix: "s" + row_id + "_" + row_id2 + "_" + row_id3 + "_"
```

The definition of `jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id3)` is inside of `subGridRowExpanded` of subgrids of all previous levels. So you can access `row_id` and `row_id2` defined on the outer scope.

I hope, that after the changes you will don't have any strange problems like the problems which you described.

here is sample of DUPLICATES

[image: 3rd grid when you click to show fourth grid]

Comment: you were right, this was a matter of duplicate id's from the data returned from the server, I corrected the queries and everything is working now.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @JoseR: I'm glad to hear that I could help you. You are welcome!