# How to access parent grid id from subgrid in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

i'm constructing a jqgrid which is working fine ... grid construction

```
if (jqent.isReq) {
    sbGrid.Append("subGrid: true,");
    sbGrid.Append("subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {");
    sbGrid.Append(" $('#' + subgrid_id).html(renderhtmlforSubgrid(subgrid_id, row_id));},");
}
```

i have a subgrid with textarea and an image control that will be rendered by the below code

```
function renderhtmlforSubgrid(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var script = '<div style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">';
    script += '<textarea class="txtCommentwatermarkOn" id="txtCommentSection" name="txtCommentSection" rows=2 cols=20>Type your comments here</textarea>';
    script += '<input onclick=\"RenderModalPopup(' + row_id + ',' + subgrid_id + ',this);\" type="image" id="image" src="../../Content/Images/commentIcon.png"/>';
    script += '</div>';

    return script;
}
```

on click of the image "RenderModalPopup" function will be triggered

```
function RenderModalPopup(rowid, tableid, event) {
    var dataFromRow = $('#tblArtifact1').jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
    var PhaseArtifactId = $('#tblArtifact1').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'ID');
    ..........................
```

Every thing is working fine... Now the issue is i'm hardcoding the grid id as "tblArtifact1" to fetch the column values. which needs to be removed. Can i get the grid id? is there any predefined parameter/function to get it?

I'm stuck up.. please help.

Comment: can u paste u r code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of callback function `subGridRowExpanded` you can use `this` variable which is initialized to the DOM of the grid (DOM of the `<table>`). So you can get `id` of the parent grid by `this.id`. If you call `renderhtmlforSubgrid` inside of `subGridRowExpanded` I would recommend you to use

```
renderhtmlforSubgrid.call(this, subgrid_id, row_id)
```

instead of

```
renderhtmlforSubgrid(subgrid_id, row_id)
```

In the case `this` inside of `renderhtmlforSubgrid` function will be not changed to global `window` object and you can have `this` which hold helpful information for you (like `this.id` for id or `$(this)` for jQuery rapper to the parent grid).

I would recommend you to consider to use `idPrefix` option in the subgrid to prevent id duplicates (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10247633/315935) for more information).

Moreover I see from your code that you are more C#/C++ developer as JavaScript developer. I had the same problems 2 years before. JavaScript has some constructions which are close to well-known other languages, but the deep semantic is really different. So JavaScript developers have many standard traps where he use existing constructions in the wrong way.

For examples: you should never use variables, properties or especially functions which name starts with capital letter. Currently `RenderModalPopup` and `PhaseArtifactId` breaks the rule. JavaScript has no classes, but one can create close constructs using functions. Inside of functions you can assign properties to `this`. Such functions are constructors of the "class" and should have first capital letter. To create instance of the "class" one should use `new`. For example `var now = new Date();`.

Closures are another example of functions in JavaScript which looks like functions, but have a lot of important differences.

Additionally I would recommend you to use more anonymous functions and function expressions (`var renderhtmlforSubgrid = function (subgrid_id, row_id) {...}`) instead of function statement (`function renderhtmlforSubgrid (subgrid_id, row_id) {...}`) and define all variables in the first line of function body. JavaScript has *no block-level variable declaration* like the most computer languages, so it's very easy to produce wrong code if you would define variables inside of JavaScript code.

The last advice would be to use [Kernighan and Ritchie's style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) of code formatting for JavaScript code independent from the style which you used to use in your favorite computer language. It will prevent you from the [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9) which can make serious errors which are difficult to localize.