# jqGrid subGridRowExpanded parameters

Tags: jqgrid

Where do I set the values that are passed to the subGridRowExpanded method. For example, I have a parent row A and I want to get the children of A so I want to pass this value to the subGridRowExpanded method.

Answer (score 3):

@SBel: I had the same issue these days afer upgrading to jqGrid v. 4.6.0. 
Oleg is - as always  - right by pointing to a "wrong" id-specification.
This happens sometimes when the generation of your JSON-String comes from an older jqGrid-Installation...
However, these lines helped me out:

```
[...],
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var rowData = $(this).getRowData(row_id);
    var uid = rowData['id'];
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`subGridRowExpanded` is *callback function*. One uses it for example to implement [Subgrid as Grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid_as_grid#definition). jqGrid set all parameters and then calls your callback function if you implemented it.

You should describe more clear your original problem: what you want to do and in which context (in which situation or inside of which callback).

Comment: I've implemented subGridRowExpanded and when I expand a row it is invoked (which is what is suppossed to happen). My question is: there are 2 parameters to that function, subgrid_id and row_id, how can I use these parameter(s) to find out information that I will use to get the subgrid.  For example, there are 3 top-level rows initially, identified as 'A', 'B', and 'C'. User clicks on the 3rd row, 'C'; I need to find out which row was clicked on so that I can pass the appropriate parameter to the service call, ie, service.html?id=C

Comment: @SBel: The second parameter is the rowid. The parameters as described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#events). So the second parameter should be 'C' in your case. So you can create new grid and use `"service.html?id="+rowid` as `url` or use `"service.html"` as `url` and `postData: {id: rowid}` as parameter. If in your case you the second parameter of `subGridRowExpanded` are initialized wrong, then you specified wrong `id` values during filling of the main grid (or didn't specified any `id` at all).

Comment: The rowid parameter is null and I don't see in the documentation how to initialize the parent table. In addition, I need to pass more than 1 parameter to the service (I was just simplifying the question).

Comment: @SBel: First of all look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4115481/315935). If you start the demo in debugger and set breakpoint inside of `subGridRowExpanded` callback you will see that `row_id` parameter will be correctly initialized to the `id` of the row which you expand. You don't post any *your code*, so it's difficult to help you more.

Comment: @SBel: Another simple example from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10178440/315935) you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalSubgrid.htm). I recommend you additionally to use `idPrefix` option like I described as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10247633/315935).